# Repeatable results from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to get repeatable results from training a tensorflow model. I looked up on how to do this. The code I used is as follows:

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'
np.random.seed(66)
rn.seed(66)
tf.set_random_seed(66)
tf.random.set_random_seed(66)
session_conf=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess=tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(),config=session_conf)
```

I trained the model and the results were:

```
Epoch 1/7
 - 20s - loss: 0.6240 - acc: 0.6862 - val_loss: 0.2289 - val_acc: 0.9333
Epoch 2/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.2085 - acc: 0.9312 - val_loss: 0.1753 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 3/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.1124 - acc: 0.9675 - val_loss: 0.1626 - val_acc: 0.9167
Epoch 4/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0712 - acc: 0.9863 - val_loss: 0.1223 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 5/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0439 - acc: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.1187 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 6/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0338 - acc: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 7/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0264 - acc: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.1074 - val_acc: 0.9667
```

I restarted the kernel and cleared all outputs then retrained again. Results are:

```
Epoch 1/7
 - 20s - loss: 0.6240 - acc: 0.6862 - val_loss: 0.2289 - val_acc: 0.9333
Epoch 2/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.2086 - acc: 0.9312 - val_loss: 0.1751 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 3/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.1125 - acc: 0.9688 - val_loss: 0.1629 - val_acc: 0.9333
Epoch 4/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0710 - acc: 0.9875 - val_loss: 0.1244 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 5/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0440 - acc: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.1264 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 6/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0343 - acc: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.1083 - val_acc: 0.9667
Epoch 7/7
 - 10s - loss: 0.0258 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.1147 - val_acc: 0.9667
```

The differences are small but does anyone know why they are not exactly the same?

Comment: Please use formatting for the results so the data is easy to read and understand

Comment: The question is also whether or not you are using sampling outside of that loop to generate your test/training data, or do any other form of randomization not shown here. Also, I don't see it right here (not too familiar with TF), but are you using GPU training by any chance?

Comment: I am using a GPU. I am not doing any other random process I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found multiple reasons for the lack of repeatability. I am using the image data generator in Keras with flow from directory. Flow from directory has an argument seed=. This needs to be set to a seed number which controls the ordering and transformations on the images. Next I looked at the model. I am using the MobileNet model. That model definition includes the specification of a "dropout rate". Since this is a random process it needs to be seeded. However there is no paramenter in the definition of the mobile net function to receive a seed input parameter.

```
def MobileNet(input_shape=None,
          alpha=1.0,
          depth_multiplier=1,
          dropout=1e-3,
          include_top=True,
          weights='imagenet',
          input_tensor=None,
          pooling=None,
          classes=1000,
          **kwargs):
"""Instantiates the MobileNet architecture.
```

To eliminate the randomness you could set the dropout rate =0 but this might lead to over training of the model.